# Inheriting/overriding WPF styles

Tags: wpf

I created style for a toggle button, defined below:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="border" Padding="5,5,5,5" CornerRadius="5" Background="#FFBFACAC" BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
          <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"/>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border">
              <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                  <GradientStop Color="#FF36587C" Offset="0.5"/>
                  <GradientStop Color="#FF122F53" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
              </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border">
              <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                  <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="0.5"/>
                  <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
              </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

I have multiple toggle buttons but I would like a way to change their border corner radius.  For example, I would like buttons with only their right border corners to be rounded, or some with no corner rounding.

Do I have to recreate the entire style for each type of rounding I need, where the only difference in each style would be the following line?

```
    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="border" Padding="5,5,5,5" CornerRadius="5" Background="#FFBFACAC" BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
```

Since the corner rounding is part of the control template, I don't think I can somehow change just a part of the template in a new style without including all of it but I am not sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alternative is to create a Custom Control, inheriting from ToggleButton.

You could then have a property called CornerRadius, and in the generic template for the class, do a TemplateBinding to this property.

If this is something you plan to use "a lot" in your project, with a bunch of variations, then a Custom Control may be the way to go.  It will also allow you to expand the number of properties later, in case you want to do further customizations.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create the entire style to change part of the control template.  I suggest putting this into a resource dictionary that you can merge as part of your window to keep the window (or control) XAML cleaner.

An easy way to do this is with Blend - add the control you want and right click it, then choose "edit template", to edit a copy of the template.