# Radiobutton style based off of custom ToggleButton

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I created a custom ToggleButton class, ToggleButtonEx, that extends ToggleButton.  ToggleButtonEx contains some dependency properties that I created in order to use them in a template.  I want to base the style of all of my radio buttons on the new toggle button style.  Here is what I have:

The ToggeButtonEx style, which defines the template:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ToggleButtonEx}">      
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ToggleButtonEx}">
...
```

The radio button style, based off of the ToggleButtonEx style:

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type local:ToggleButtonEx}}" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
```

This does not work though.  According to msdn,

> "If you create a style with a
>   TargetType property and base it on
>   another style that also defines a
>   TargetType property, the target type
>   of the derived style must be the same
>   as or be derived from the type of the
>   base style."

Since radio button is derived from ToggleButton and not ToggleButtonEx, I can't apply the style an I need the toggle button style to be based off of ToggleButtonEx or else I can't use my custom dependency properties in the template.  Is there a way to do this?

**UPDATE:**

Here is my requirement.  Maybe someone can help with an alternate solution.

I want to display radio buttons as toggle buttons, so that they look like toggle buttons but maintain the radio button mutually exclusive functionality.  This was not hard to do. I created a style targeting ToggleButton to set up my desired toggle button style and then created a new style targeting RadioButton which was based off of the toggle button style.

Now in my ToggleButton style, I change the ControlTemplate to make the button have rounded corners.  I decided that I would like different buttons to have different CornerRadius', or no rounding at all.  I asked how that can be done in this post:

[Inheriting/overriding WPF styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752095/inheriting-overriding-wpf-styles)

One suggestion was to create a custom ToggleButton and add a new property so that it can be used in a TemplateBinding.  I tried that but it looks like if it is possible, I am not doing it right.  I would like to avoid adding a new style each time I need a different value of CornerRadius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think there's a way to do it unless maybe you derive a custom RadioButton from your ToggleButtonEx duplicating all the functionality existent in RadioButton. However I doubt that's much fun - may not even be completely possible.

However maybe we'd have some suggestions on how to solve your problem in another, slightly different way; you could try outlining the broad requirements that dictated the inclusion of a DependencyProperty? Maybe there's even a built-in feature that can help you but nobody could think of suggesting it because nobody has any idea it might help you.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I have updated my original post with my requirements.

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing something, but why not inherit straight from RadioButton?

Comment: Hmm.  You are right.  I created a RadioButtonEx that extends RadioButton and then just created a style to alter its ControlTemplate.  I didn't need to reference ToggleButton anywhere.  Thanks for the help Alex.